# Injecting Spring bean into EJB3

Tags: spring, ejb-3.0, code-injection

I have created one Remote StatelessSession Bean and I want to inject Spring bean into my UserServiceImpl EJB.

```
@Stateless

@Interceptors(SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor.class)

public class UserServiceImpl implements IUserService{


    @Autowired

    IRegisterService registerService;
```

As per the documentation, I have added beanRefContext.xml into classpath which has entry for spring bean configuration.

My problem is when I am trying to deploy this EJB without `@Interceptors(SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor.class)`, it gets deployed and runs as expected without spring bean injection.

But when I am injecting bean into EJB deployment fails with following exception:

```
at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:119) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [rt.jar:1.6.0_29]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [rt.jar:1.6.0_29]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_29]

Caused by: java.lang.ArrayStoreException: sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy
        at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseClassArray(AnnotationParser.java:653) [rt.jar:1.6.0_29]
        at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseArray(AnnotationParser.java:460) [rt.jar:1.6.0_29]
        at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseMemberValue(AnnotationParser.java:286) [rt.jar:1.6.0_29]
        at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotation(AnnotationParser.java:222) [rt.jar:1.6.0_29]
        at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations2(AnnotationParser.java:69) [rt.jar:1.6.0_29]
        at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations(AnnotationParser.java:52) [rt.jar:1.6.0_29]
        at java.lang.Class.initAnnotationsIfNecessary(Class.java:3070) [rt.jar:1.6.0_29]
        at java.lang.Class.getAnnotation(Class.java:3029) [rt.jar:1.6.0_29]
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.BusinessViewAnnotationProcessor.getRemoteBusinessInterfaces(BusinessViewAnnotationProcessor.java:150)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.BusinessViewAnnotationProcessor.processViewAnnotations(BusinessViewAnnotationProcessor.java:123)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.BusinessViewAnnotationProcessor.deploy(BusinessViewAnnotationProcessor.java:98)


        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        ... 5 more
```

Has anyone experienced this issue and has a solution for it?

Answer (score 0):

I know exactly why this exceptions happens, this is caused by the JDK bug [JDK-7183985](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-7183985). The underlying issue is likely that your container can't load `SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor`. That's likely a packaging issue in your application. Please provide more details about how you package your application and how you package Spring in your application.